# NSPopover: how to remove border?

Tags: objective-c, nspopover

I' ve an `NSPopover` where i put my own `NSView` subclass to customize his content. I used an empty view with only a subview to have a "bar" on the top. The problem is that the `NSPopover` seems to have a sort of border all around itself and I've this ugly effect. Anyone have an idea how to fix that? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Did you solve it by now? I would be interested in your solution.

Comment: Yes, I' ve used the Rebel framework that work great to solve that problem. There are some other issue but for the topic of that question the solution posted below is correct. I don' t check the answer as correct because this is not a solution for this problem but is a wide workaround that use totally different kind of control.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I just ran into the same issue.

If you are targeting OS X 10.10 or later you can just write:

```
popover = NSPopover()
popover.appearance = NSAppearance(named: "NSAppearanceNameAqua")
```

This should kill the border.